# Include last date in range between dates in php

Tags: php, date

I have found a problem with using DatePeriod which might be because I am stupid lol.
As you can see I have added +1 to my end date because I want to include the last date of the range.
But my issue is when I have ending date 31 it makes it to 32 which is not a date so it throws out an error.
Is there a way to include the ending date or to make the +1 work?

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($event['startyear'].$event['startmonth'].$event['startdate']),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime($event['endyear'].$event['endmonth'].$event['enddate'] +1)  
);

foreach ($period as $savedDate) {   
    echo $savedDate;
}
```

Comment: U can surroun with try catch block

Comment: Yes I see but would the 31 event still be shown?

Comment: If u want it yes! In 'catch' block you can handle it

Comment: @rm596 - Although that technically could work, it is not the right way to approach/solve this problem.

Comment: I get the feeling this has nothing to do with javascript, HTML or CSS.

Comment: I put this in the tags because I have this in my script sorry if I confused anybody.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should create the date object for the initial date (without the +1) and then increment the day of that object by 1 day.

For example:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($event['endyear'].$event['endmonth'].$event['enddate']);
$date2 = new DateTime($event['endyear'].$event['endmonth'].$event['enddate']);
$date2->modify('+1 day');

$period = new DatePeriod($date1, new DateInterval('P1D'), $date2);
```

Comment: So does that mean put my query information in a strtotime and then add a day? Sorry I am pretty new to php

Comment: See my updated example. Create 2 date objects, increment the second one by a day, then pass both to `DatePeriod`

Comment: The only issue is that when the date ends in 31 it is not added other than that it works fine

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$endDate = mktime(0,0,0, $event['endmonth'], $event['enddate'], $event['endyear']); 

$counter = 0; 

while($endDate >= $date = mktime(0,0,0, $event['startmonth'], $event['startdate']+$counter++,     $event['startyear']) ) {    
  echo date('Y/m/d', $date); 
}
```

Comment: try now. Sorry, my fault